# Creative Audigy value soundblaster not working in windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, creative

I have installed Creative Audigy value soundblastercard in my machine
Earlier it was working in Windows XP
But now after moving to Windows Vista, the card is not working
The speakers or the drivers are not recognised as well

any help?

Edit:
tried to google for vista creative drivers,no use :(

Comment: I had the same problem with my old Audigy based card.  Creative did not officially support Vista/7 for them.  I finally got them working with a different driver, but I don't recall how.  I don't have that computer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Creative Audigy Value is supported by the kx project. But you can give it a try: http://kxproject.com/